# Class 'LaravelLocalization' not found

Tags: php, laravel

In the app.php file I changed the locale from "en" to "de". But now accessing "project.test" it shows "`Laravel default locale is not in the supportedLocales array.`" in LaravelLocalization file. Do you know how to solve the error?

Maybe is because of a package installed for translation, but I alredy remove the package with "`composer remove mcamara/laravel-localization`" it shows another error "`Class 'LaravelLocalization' not found`
".

Do you know how to properly remove the package and correct the error?

I change from    "'locale' => 'en'" to "'locale' => 'de'".

Comment: You need to create a file called “de” translation before setting the application language to “de”. https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: Thanks, but I already removed the package, but I dont know why it appears "Class 'LaravelLocalization' not found".

Comment: I removed the file Translate.php from Middleware folder and now appear an error in the file "ClassLoader.php", the error is: "/Translate.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory"".

Comment: The first error you’re getting is because you changed the locale from en to de. If you change the locale back to en that error will go away. The second error you’re getting is probably because you have another class or file referencing the `LaravelLocalization` class using the `use ...\LaravelLocalization`

Comment: Thanks, but Im not using that, do you know how to find the file that can have the issue?

Comment: The easiest way is to do a find on the whole project.